# How to make a metallic material that will carry metallic-ness over to Unity (or other game engine)?

Tags: modeling, rendering, unity

I have a game I am attempting to make that includes a toaster companion that you must escort home. Only problem is that the render pipeline in unity will not allow me to make good metallic materials for the chromey look i want for my toaster, so I must do it in blender. I see that there are many tutorials for making metal in blender, but I don't know how many of those characteristics will carry over in an .fbx like how they look in blender.

If anyone could tell me how exactly you can make sure your model will look exactly how it will in fbx format and in a game engine, or recommend a good tutorial that would be greatly appreciated.

If it makes any difference I use URP in Unity for anybody who also uses it.

Comment: I don't think there's anything special you can do in blender - how metallic things are rendered is a function of the shader system that is rendering it. For almost all systems that incorporate a "metallic" component, the metallic map is just a black and white texture map with white areas being metal and back areas being non-metal.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#57541